# Issue when updating entries in database using Play and EbeanServer

Tags: java, database, transactions, playframework-2.0, ebean

I am using EbeanServer with play framework to interact with my PostGreSQL database.

I am using Programmatic transactions to retrieve/update entries in the database as described on this [Link](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/transactions/) under "Programmatic Transactions". `ebeanServer.save()`, `ebeanServer.delete()` and `ebeanServer.insert()` are working very well for me when I commit the transaction for new entries.

But when i try **updating** existing entries (using `ebeanServer.update()` or `ebeanServer.save()`), the entries are not updated in my database. In the meantime, I am using `ebeanServer.delete()` followed by an `ebeanServer.insert()` to update my entries but this is very ineffective.

I made sure to commit my transactions using `ebeanServer.commitTransaction();`and finally `ebeanServer.endTransaction();`.

How can I resolve such an issue since I couldn't find any related topics on stackoverflow?

Thank you!

UPDATE:
A small log shows that the update is not being executed: (It should update the discriminant and dictionary entries! Although, it is selecting them from the table when I need them!

```
[info] o.j.ConnectionLogger - connect to URL jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ProjetEeaah?user=postgres&password=0000 for user postgres
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.id c0, t0.language c1, t0.topic c2, t0.topic_stop_words c3, t0.end_session_flag c4, t0.end_of_execution_in_background c5 from session t0 where t0.id = 7  ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - insert into cluster (session_id) values (7);
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - insert into ideas (sentence, treated_idea, session_id, cluster_id) values ('plays',N,7,9);
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.id c0, t0.stop_word c1 from session_stop_words t0 where t0.session_id = 7 ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.id c0, t0.lemma c1, t0.derivative c2, t0.derivative_freq c3, t0.session_id c4 from lemmas_and_derivatives_used_in_session t0 where t0.session_id = 7 ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - insert into idea_word_set_without_stop_words (word, freq, session_id, idea_id) values ('play',1,7,41);
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - insert into cluster_word_freq (word, freq, session_id, cluster_id) values ('play',1,7,9);
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.id c0, t0.word c1, t0.freq c2, t0.session_id c3 from dictionary t0 where t0.session_id = 7 ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.id c0, t0.discriminant c1, t0.freq c2, t0.session_id c3 from discriminants t0 where t0.session_id = 7 ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - select t0.id c0, t0.lemma c1, t0.derivative c2, t0.derivative_freq c3, t0.session_id c4 from lemmas_and_derivatives_used_in_session t0 where t0.session_id = 7 ;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - insert into discriminant_freq_of_lemmas_per_cluster (lemma, freq, session_id, cluster_id) values ('play',1,7,9);
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - insert into lemmas_and_derivatives_used_per_cluster (lemma, derivative, derivative_freq, session_id, cluster_id) values ('play','plays',1,7,9);
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - delete from lemmas_and_derivatives_used_in_session where id=21;
[info] o.j.StatementLogger - insert into lemmas_and_derivatives_used_in_session (id, lemma, derivative, derivative_freq, session_id) values (21,'play','plays',8,7);
```

Update 2: This is part of the code

```
//I am using ebeanServer.find... in an earlier part of the code to retrieve the
// entries from the database and as seen in the log above it is working fine!
//I checked and the if condition is valid and it is executing the inner block!
            if(dicoContainsWord){

                //get dictionary entry and discriminant entry
                Dictionary currentDicoEntry = dictionary
                        .stream()
                        .filter(o -> o.word.equals(currentWord)).findFirst()
                        .get();

                Discriminants currentDiscriminantEntry = discriminants.stream()
                        .filter(o -> o.discriminant.equals(currentWord)).findFirst()
                        .get();

                //update Frequencies in dictionary
                currentDicoEntry.freq=currentDicoEntry.freq + currentWordfreq;

                //updatedDictionaryEntries.add(currentDicoEntry);

                //update frequencies in discriminants
                currentDiscriminantEntry.freq= currentDiscriminantEntry.freq+1; //increment by 1
                //updatedDiscriminantEntries.add(currentDiscriminantEntry);

                //TODO now working fine but tryto change delete/insert to update
                //UPDATE ENTRIES

                //ebeanServer.delete(currentDicoEntry);
                //ebeanServer.delete(currentDiscriminantEntry);
                //ebeanServer.insert(currentDicoEntry);
                //ebeanServer.insert(currentDiscriminantEntry);

    //This is where it should update these entries
                ebeanServer.update(currentDicoEntry);
                ebeanServer.update(currentDiscriminantEntry);

    //The ebeanServer.commitTransaction() is executed in a later part of the code! and it is always working
            }
```

**EDIT** (Problem Solved):

I have resolved my problem by defining Getters and setters for each Model.
Before that, I was simply using `objectName.attribute = new value` which ebeanServer was not taking into consideration during the updates.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in your logs when the update is called? That would be a good place to start. If you are update your question with them, if you aren't you might have written your commit code incorrectly and your update isn't being committed

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't show the "update" in the log. It is not executing it! although I'm sure that the statement just before it is executed @CanadianCoder

Comment: Perhaps you could post the code where the update is called

Comment: @CanadianCoder I have added part of the code and log